# Python's Queue collection doesn't release the memory

Tags: python, multithreading

I have an application where I stuff lots of data in a queue, then workers empty that data.
I am using queue because it is blocked, so I don't need to apply lock all the times.

So there are times when that queue is stuffed with 1 million items of string data. Each of the item taking about 80 bytes of memory.

At some, in peak usage, python starts taking around 3 GB of memory. Then when consumer empties the entire queue, python is still taking 3 GB of memory. I am checking memory using `ps` command. What is this phenomenon? Is this high memory usage because of swollen queue at the first place? If it is so, what can be done to keep it in check? Are there any other better collections in python as a replacement for queue?

Comment: Paste some code thing, we can't guess ur code ...

Comment: what should I show in code? It's quite ordinary. What's important is the consequence. Just usual queue operation `put` and `get`

Comment: @Shades88 did you get any solution

Answer (score 0):

Python (generally) doesn't return the memory it used to the operating system. Once the queue is empty, your process will hold on to the memory that was allocated to the queue. If you were to add another 3GB worth of data to the queue, Python should reuse the memory it already holds, rather than requesting more from the OS (i.e., you shouldn't see its memory allocation grow further).

Comment: yes but his question is about reducing the transient memory footprint and is a valid question imho